# newlineCharacterSet returning 5 lines instead of 3

Tags: objective-c, ios

I download a file which contains 3 lines directly under each other,
but my array appears to skip one line for every set.  In my array, tangible results appear in positions: 0, 2, and 4 instead of positions 0,1,  and 2.

Also, will this timeout after a few seconds? I just see an interval, is that the timeout?

```
    NSTimeInterval timeStamp = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
        NSNumber *timeStampObj = [NSNumber numberWithDouble: timeStamp];
        NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://192.168.1.30/ios/info.php?a=APP1&s=%i",timeStampObj]];
        NSURLRequest* request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:0 timeoutInterval:5];
        NSURLResponse* response=nil;
        NSError* error=nil;
        NSData* data=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
        NSString* fileContents = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];
        if ([fileContents length] == 0) return;

        NSArray* allLinedStrings = [fileContents componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]];

        if ([allLinedStrings count] == 0) {

        } else {
            NSString* Title = [allLinedStrings objectAtIndex:0];
            NSString* Description = [allLinedStrings objectAtIndex:2];
            NSString* Url = [allLinedStrings objectAtIndex:4];

        }
```

Comment: If you made this file on Windows, it will have two newline characters at the end of every line.  Might this be causing something?

Comment: If you can open it in Xcode, under preferences, it will allow you to highlight new lines.

Comment: the file is generated by a php script on a nix based machine. echo "line1\r\nline2\r\nline3";

Comment: it should be only \n now shouldn't it....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the file is reliably separated by "\r\n", then `-componentsSeparatedByString:` should work for you.

```
 NSArray* allLinedStrings = [fileContents componentsSeparatedByString:@"\r\n"];
```